# Using bootstrap default navbar, "Toggle navigation" button unresponsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, navbar

So I get the following problem when using the default navbar from bootstrap. The "toggle navigation" button is unresponsive: http://imgur.com/2rRcgxA

This is the code I put in the header file (I'm doing "One Month Rails"):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pinteresting</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li> 
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

And this is the version of bootstrap I'm using in gemfile:

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.4.2'

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get the navbar to display properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added 
//= require bootstrap 
into assets/javascript/application.js ?